# ContentDialog is raising error when we trying to show

Tags: popup, winui-3, winui, contentdialog

It always shows " This element is already associated with a XamlRoot, it cannot be associated with a different one until it is removed from the previous XamlRoot "

Also its raising error when we set XamlRoot =  this.Content.XamlRoot;

Can anybody explain why this behaviour is happening and how could we resolve that ?

Comment: Please show some reproducible code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As far as the error is concerned, *a XAML element can only be added to a XAML tree once. If you want to move a part of your UI from one window to another, you have to manage its placement in the XAML tree*. See [Reuse XAML elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/app-window#reuse-xaml-elements) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying this code and then modifying it to your needs:

```
private async void ShowDialogButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog
    {
        Title = "Hello!",
        Content = "This is a simple ContentDialog.",
        PrimaryButtonText = "OK"
    };

    dialog.PrimaryButtonClick += delegate
    {
        // Do something when the user clicks the primary (OK) button.
    };

    dialog.XamlRoot = this.Content.XamlRoot;  // Set XamlRoot of the dialog.
    await dialog.ShowAsync(); // Show the dialog.
}
```

But to really answer your question, you'd need to provide your code and more details in your question.

Comment: Please accept my answer and upvote it if it helped you!

Comment: Actually i have set XamlRoot of dialog ,I got this error [ This element is already associated with a XamlRoot, it cannot be associated with a different one until it is removed from the previous XamlRoot ] . I'm just asking why the behaviour is happening ?

Comment: If i need to move from mainwindow ui to another window , we can try to reuse that content dialog .

Comment: @Codingtime did you already set the XamlRoot of the dialog? You can only set it once, unless you want to clear it with `dialog.XamlRoot = null` and then set it again. But the code example I gave works great for me - - no errors are thrown.

Comment: Yes it wont throw a error when we have dialog in mainwindow itself and execute by setting xaml root . when we want to move that to another window we need to set again but even though i have assigned it throws me error thats why i posted . Is that clear now ?

Comment: @Codingtime Again, [*a XAML element can only be added to a XAML tree once. If you want to move a part of your UI from one window to another, you have to manage it's placement in the XAML tree*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/app-window#reuse-xaml-elements). For example, `ColorPickerContainer.Children.Remove(colorPicker); Grid appWindowRootGrid = new Grid(); appWindowRootGrid.Children.Add(colorPicker); colorPickerAppWindow = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync(); ElementCompositionPreview.SetAppWindowContent(colorPickerAppWindow, appWindowRootGrid);`